# How do I find the GraphicsDevice where an external process' window is opened

Tags: java, selenium, multiple-monitors

I need to find the `GraphicsDevice` (e.g. the physical monitor) where an external process has opened its window.  To grab screen shots to catch changes WRT older versions. We're talking apps running on localhost, JS is heavily used.

In my case I have a Java process (based on Selenium) that opens a browser window and needs to grab a screen shot of it (using `java.awt.Robot`), unfortunately the display where the window is opened depends on where the browser remembers that it was the last time it was closed.

So, is there any way I can have my Java process find out which `GraphicsDevice` the browser window was opened on?

Comment: BTW - what sort of URLs are we talking about?  Do the site(s) use JS?  Why not use a web service that specializes in providing renderings of web pages?

Comment: We're talking apps running on localhost, of which to grab screenshots to catch changes wrt older versions. JS is heavily used.

Comment: *"catch changes wrt older versions."*  Surely CVS (or perhaps a clever CMS) is better at tracking changes than comparing images.

Comment: Now that I read more about Selenium in the info page, I find it hard to believe it does not have something built-in to serve this use-case.

Comment: You know Selenium can take screenshots, right?

Comment: Yes, selenium can handle everything w.r.t screenshots *except* for grabbing them from a secondary display if the window happens to open there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (very crude) way to do it is to take a screen-shot before the call to `Desktop.browse()`, and another 'several moments later'.  ..Then compare them for the region that is different.

This might be fouled up if the user has any animated elements on the desk top (e.g. a clock).

---

An alternate route might (untested) be as follows.  Since you effectively control the environment and content, it is possible to:

1. Load the 'screenshot' page in a frame of a framed document.
2. Load an applet in another frame.
3. Have JS determine the content area of the target frame, and report that to the applet.  Applet determines a screen shot area from a combination of its own location and the content area.
4. The applet reports the area to (sand-boxed) the localhost or (trusted) any socket it wants.
5. The screenshot app. use the information from the applet to control the `Robot`.  If the applet is trusted, *it* might grab the screenshot and write it to disk (and skip the 'report' step entirely).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid something like this, but I guess I'll have to go this route if I can't find a more robust way…

Comment: Unfortunately, it is hard to make this technique 'close to robust' either.  There are many dynamic elements on desk-tops these days.  Then there is the matter of knowing how long a browser will take to appear.  With disks set to 'power saver' it might take a while for the disk to spin up, & the browser to be loaded and then display a page from a connection of unknown speed.

Comment: I'm going to have to go for a variation of this. Basically I'll grab a screen shot of each display, change the browser window's background from white to red and grab new shots comparing them to the earlier to find which display contains my window. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.  Keep us informed if you have any problems.  Surprised that Selenium does not support multiple screens. :(

Answer (score 1):

`GraphicsDevice[]` devices can returns that, but (I never tested) if is there profesional GPU with `Multi GPU Cores` or chaned `GPU in SLI Mode`, then this `Array` is multiplayed, you can testing (this code required simple modifications for Runtime) that with code pieces from `SwingX`

```
public static Point getPointForCentering(JInternalFrame window) {
        try {
            //assert window != null;
            Point mousePoint = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            GraphicsDevice[] devices = GraphicsEnvironment
                    .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
            for (GraphicsDevice device : devices) {
                Rectangle bounds = device.getDefaultConfiguration().
                    getBounds();
                    //check to see if the mouse cursor is within these bounds
                if (mousePoint.x >= bounds.x && mousePoint.y >= bounds.y &&
                    mousePoint.x <= (bounds.x + bounds.width) && mousePoint.y 
                    <= (bounds.y + bounds.height)) {
                    int screenWidth = bounds.width;//this is it
                    int screenHeight = bounds.height;
                    int width = window.getWidth();
                    int height = window.getHeight();
                    return new Point(((screenWidth - width) / 2) + bounds.x,
                       ((screenHeight - height) / 2) + bounds.y);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.log(Level.FINE, e.getLocalizedMessage() + 
               " - this can occur do to a Security exception in sandboxed apps");
        }
        return new Point(0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but doesn't this only get me the display where the mouse cursor is? This might be different from the display where the browser window was opened.

Comment: as I mentioned, this code required simple modification 1) find the Container by Bounds or PC's monitor 2 ) find COntainer where is Mouse 3) finding available monitors and resolution